# SQL Server create audit for every modified column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create sql server audit for every modified column but i got error, this is my code :

```
BEGIN
  -- Type the SQL Here.
    DECLARE @event_type varchar(42)

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted)
        IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted)
            SELECT @event_type = 'U'
    ELSE
            SELECT @event_type = 'I'
    ELSE
        IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted)
            SELECT @event_type = 'D'
        ELSE
    --no rows affected - cannot determine event
    SELECT @event_type = 'UN'

    IF NEW.Code <> OLD.Code THEN  
        INSERT INTO CountryAuditTrail (Id, CountryId, Type, Field, OldValue, NewValue, CreatedAt, CreatedBy) 
        VALUES (NEWID(), Old.Id, @event_type, 'Code', Old.Code, New.Code, NEW.ModifiedAt, NEW.ModifiedBy);

    IF NEW.Name <> OLD.Name THEN  
        INSERT INTO CountryAuditTrail (Id, CountryId, Type, Field, OldValue, NewValue, CreatedAt, CreatedBy) 
        VALUES(NEWID(), Old.Id, @event_type, 'Name', Old.Name, New.Name, NEW.ModifiedAt, NEW.ModifiedBy);

    IF NEW.Status <> OLD.Status THEN  
        INSERT INTO CountryAuditTrail (Id, CountryId, Type, Field, OldValue, NewValue, CreatedAt, CreatedBy) 
        VALUES(NEWID(), Old.Id, @event_type, 'Status', Old.Status, New.Status, NEW.ModifiedAt, NEW.ModifiedBy);
END
```

I got this `NEW` and `OLD` from other stackoverflow solution, but it not work. and the error is :

> Incorrect syntax near THEN

How to solve this?

So it can record to audit trail table for every column in insert or updated column

---

What I want to achieve is to record specified modified column using trigger.

In the `Country` table, I only specified to `Code`, `Name` and `Status` column

Insert trigger :

insert to table `CountryAudit` for every code, name and status

update trigger :

check if `old.code` and `new.code` different, if different then insert to `CountryAudit`

and other column too

Comment: There is too many Incorrect syntax in your query.. could you provide some sample data and expect the result?  How could you get  `NEW.Code <> OLD.Code` be your condition?

Comment: I got it from stack overflow, okay i update it

Comment: Why not use a DDL trigger ?

Comment: becaus this is my first time create trigger still learning about it, if you have better suggestion, please share to us, thank you very much for new knowledge for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is sooo not the right way to write a trigger in SQL Server.  You need to realize that `inserted` and `deleted` can have more than one row.

So, you need to use set operations.

If I follow the logic correctly, then you want something like this:

```
begin
    insert into CountryAuditTrail (Id, CountryId, Type, Field, OldValue, NewValue, CreatedAt, CreatedBy) 
        select newid(), coalesce(i.id, d.id),
               (case when i.id is null then 'D'
                     when d.id is null then 'I'
                     else 'U'
                end),
               v.col, v.oldvalue, v.newvalue,
               i.ModifiedAt, i.ModifiedBy
        from inserted i full join
             deleted d
             on i.id = d.id cross apply
             (values ('code', i.code, d.code),
                     ('name', i.name, d.name),
                     ('status', i.status, d.status)
             ) v(col, newvalue, oldvalue)
        where oldvalue <> newvalue or
              (oldvalue is null and newvalue is not null) or
              (oldvalue is not null and newvalue is null);
end;
```

Comment: thanks, Okay, i tried it, got error, please fix `select newid()` to `select (newid() ...` next error is incorrect syntax near ','

Comment: @yozawiratama . . . The parenthesis before `newid()` is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax wrong

Use this syntax

```
IF `condition` BEGIN
   statement;
END
```